# How can I represent mixed states in Q#?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, q#

I have a mixed state with a density matrices corresponding to $\rho=\sum_0^{2^n-1}p_i|i\rangle\langle i|$. How would i represent this in Q#? How would I go about applying Unitary Operations $U$ on this mixed state in Q#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be helpful to step back and look at what a density matrix describes: a probability distribution over projectors onto pure states. In your example, for instance, $\rho$ represents a distribution in which $|\psi\rangle = |i\rangle$ with probability $p_i$. That is, a density operator describes a probability over an *ensemble* of state vectors.

From that perspective, we easily write pseudocode for a quantum program that prepares $\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$:

- Draw a random $i$ with probability $p_i$.
- Prepare the pure state $|\psi_i\rangle$.

Thinking of state vectors like $|\psi_i\rangle$ as [quantum programs that prepare those states](https://www.cgranade.com/blog/2019/09/08/this-is-not-a-qubit.html), this is already a complete description of how to prepare $\rho$. You can, for instance, use the [`PrepareArbitraryState` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate) to prepare each $|\psi_i\rangle$ on a freshly allocated register of qubits.

In practice, however, you'll often have a much more efficient implementation of the state preparation programs for each $|\psi_i\rangle$. For example, there's no need to use [`PrepareArbitraryState` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate) to prepare $|+\rangle$, as the [`H` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.h) does just fine.

This is, for instance, how the [`PrepareSingleQubitIdentity` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparesinglequbitidentity) prepares the particular mixed state $\rho =  / 2$ on a single qubit.